# LibreELEC_RPi4 (System.tar.xz) unzipped changes to config.txt

Tags: hdmi, pi-4, noobs

trying to connect Pi4 to a Hitachi TV (pretty old - mid 2000's), however it has the HDMI port. So my Pi4 is connected.

SD card is with OS's on it (NOOBS).

Any idea why Pi4 is not booting up? I have selected a PC channel on TV, just displays (No PC Input) in TV.

I want to see if I change few settings in the config file for HDMI will make the difference.

If I make changes to the (System.tar.xz) unzipped folder System/config.txt, I presume I have to zip the folder again for those changes to be applied? Will the Pi read the changes from the zipped folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use NOOBS. Instead flash a Rasbian image direct to the SD Card.

Comment: May I ask why is that the case? Will I be able to install other OSs on SD after?

Comment: We have seen [many problems with NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=NOOBS+problem) here on this site. Having problems, so the first advice in conjunction with NOOBS is not to use it. No one of the experienced users here use it. If you still want to use NOOBS, then temporary flashing Raspbian direct is an option to reduce complexity and use a well known official supported operating system that you can expect most support.